# What to use as split field or target workspace with Split tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, splitting

I'm trying to use the split tool in arcgis 10.1 but I dont know what I should use as the split field or my target workspace.

W:\S&P\s&p techs\Emily\Geodatabase\Geodatabase.gdb
this is what I have as my target workspace but it says it's empty.

Comment: also, sorry, I'm trying to split a polyline with a polygon!

Comment: I don't have advanced licensing, so cannot test this tool, but can you try setting your target workspace to a path with no '&' characters? E.g. 'W:\myGDB.gdb'

Comment: @Emily Fratin please edit the original question with more information. not in the comments section.

Comment: Do you actually mean you are trying to split a polygon feature with a polyline feature?

Answer (score 1):

The split tool creates multiple feature classes based on the Input feature class. The split field will be used to determine how many new feature classes will be made, based on how many unique values are in this field.

Having the `&` in your path is not an issue. However, make sure all values in your split field are alphanumberic, do not start with a number, and have no spaces.